# containment feature of jQuery does not work when 'float:right' is set on parent

Tags: jquery, css, draggable, jsplumb

I have following HTML. Notice that 'drop' is `'float: right'`

```
<div id="drop" style = "border:solid #1E90FF 3px; border-radius:25px; height:400px;  width:700px; float:right;">
</div>
<div id="drag" style = "border: 2px solid #8AC007; border-radius:15px; height:150px; width:150px;">
</div>
```

I am trying to drag the clone of `#drag` and drop it in `#drop`.

I wanted to contain this within `#drop` using `containment:$("#drop")` but it's not working.

It is containing the draggable element as if the droppable element is in left.

```
<script>
     $("#drag").draggable ({
         helper : "clone",
         revert:"invalid"    

     });
     $("#drop").droppable({
         accept:"#drag",
         drop: function(event,ui){
             var cloneDiv = $(ui.helper).clone();
             cloneDiv.attr('class',"cloned");
             $(this).append(cloneDiv);

             jsPlumb.ready(function(){ 
                   jsPlumb.draggable($(".cloned"), {containment:$("#drop")});
             });    
         }
     });
</script>
```

I want to contain the draggable element within droppable element.

Does anybody have an idea on how to solve this? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Give `drag` to `float:left`

Comment: Thats the requirement, drag needs to be placed at right side of the screen.